# Create text with custom 3d meshes

Tags: text-object

So i created a custom series of letters (3d meshes) and i wanted to know if there was an easy way of alligning them so that i don't have to do it manually every time. Like a mesh text generator with geometry nodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use custom [Object Font](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/texts/properties.html#id6) for this.

This feature allows you to use regular 3D objects of any type (meshes, curves, etc) as font glyph replacements for your text object.

Under the *Properties Window > Text Object Data > Font > Transform > Font Object* you must specify a custom font name prefix.

[image]

This prefix will determine which objects are picked by Blender as part of your object font family. If you type `MyCustomObjectFont.` in this field Blender will look for all objects named `MyCustomObjectFont.XXXX` where `XXXX`is the name of the glyph it will replace.

If you want to create a custom "a" character it should be named `MyCustomObjectFont.a` or `MyCustomObjectFont.A` for a capital "A", and `MyCustomObjectFont.!` for a custom exclamation mark character.

After this activate vertex instancing under *Properties Window > Object > Instancing > Vertices* for your text object. Now any time a character you type matches an object you created it will replace the font provided glyph with your custom 3D object.

The objects are duplicated so that their center is positioned at the lower right corner of the corresponding characters, so position their origins accordingly.

Beware that this doesn't take into account custom object dimensions, and always uses kerning from the specified base font file. If your objects are too big or have very different scales they may overlap and require manual adjustment.